# How can I use cheats to summon a villager in Minecraft? (Then have it make more?)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing Survival and I found a village with a couple villagers. I left to explore for a couple days and when I came back only one was left.

Normally, to make more I would use cheats to change into Creative, get a spawn egg, make a couple villagers, and then change back to Survival.  But there's some kind of glitch because if I go on Creative and change to Survival, it won't let me break or place down any blocks. This happens on both my computers, and I can place down blocks if I change back to Creative.

Anyway, is there any kind of cheat I can use to easily spawn a certain villager without changing to Creative? All cheats are enabled even though I'm in Survival. Also, how can I get the villagers to breed quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. So if I want to be able to go into Survival but be able to still break blocks and place them, I need to change it to gamemode 0, not gamemode 2. This way, I can get a spawn egg and make more villagers, but still be able to play survival.

Comment: Yes. Gamemode 0 is Survival, 1 is creative, 2 is "Adventure mode" and 3 is "Spectator mode"

Comment: Yeah, you can't break blocks in adventure mode. Only survival and creative

Answer (score 5):

You can try `/give <Your Username/@p/@a/@r> 383 1 120`, which will give you a spawn egg.
otherwise use the `/summon Villager ~ ~ ~` command to spawn one at your current location.

You can enter this command into your chat box (provided cheats is turned on) in your Single-player world by pressing <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the chat box: `/summon villager`, and one will spawn.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need cheats. You can craft a spawner egg for villagers with an emerald block and two diamonds.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a joke?